# При запуске миграции возникла ошибка

Tags: laravel

У меня возникла ошибка во время выполнения команды:  php artisan migrate.

SQLSTATE[42S01]: 
Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос.

Comment: спасибо за советы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно сбросить миграции или обновить, **внимание** все таблицы удаляются данные записываются по-новому.

```
php artisan migrate:reset
```

или

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```